# What is the other way to move on next line in C++ programming

Tags: c++

One way to move on next line is `cout << endl;` I know there is another way to move on next line. But, I do not know what is that. Can anyone tell me.

Comment: or `cout << '\n';`

Comment: @RoiHatam Why diddn't you write that as an answer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  You are right

Comment: This is a strange question. Why do you need two ways of doing the same thing? What is your programming problem that makes you think you need two ways to move to the next line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use:

```
std::cout << '\n';
```

The only difference is that the stream won't be flushed.

Comment: Also possible to use `std::cout << "\n"`.   Net effect is the same, but the mechanism (e.g. which overload of  `operator<<()`) differs

Comment: I do not use std:: Can i write cout << "\n";

Comment: You can only write `cout << '\n';` if you are using `using namespace std;` in the beginning of your code.

Comment: @Roi _"You can only write  ..."_ Wrong! _`using namespace std;`_ [Infamous!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know it is a bad practice to use `using namespace std;`

Comment: @Roi So why do you recommend that then?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didn't recommend it. He asked if he can use it so I answered. I will edit my comment. I meant the code won't be compiled without it.

Comment: @Roi Just look what I've been commenting about that very same question.

Comment: Thank You. Actually I am a student and still use "using namespace std;"

Comment: @Student28 _"Actually I am a student ..."_ How does that justify bad programming habits?

Comment: @Student28 But you are using it. What do you think `using namespace std;` does actually? Don't use code you don't understand yet.

Comment: I do not know what it does.. But I can search it.

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```
std::cout << '\n';
```

instead. That would have the advantage that the stream isn't flushed at the same time.

---

Note:
On Windows OS it might be required to write

```
std::cout << '\r' << '\n';
```

or

```
std::cout << "\r\n";
```

to get correct line endings.

Comment: I do not use std::   Can i write cout << "\r\n";

Comment: @Student28 If you use `using std::cout;` somewhere before you can do that, yes.

Comment: I don't think the `\r\n` stuff is needed, iirc, the implementation maps the escape sequence `\n` to some proper newline sequence for the given platform.

Comment: @Baum Might depend on the compiler used. But usually it's mapped, yes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -- you don't have to write `"\r\n"` on any compiler that conforms to the language definition. Inserting `'\n'` starts a new line; it's up to the runtime library to get this right.